# CSS Position absolute span without hidden by other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problem is base on this image:

[image]

As you see in the image above, some of my *helper number(span)* are getting cropped(big green arrow).

So I've tried using *z-index: 100000;* to bring all of them up, but the result is not as I expect.

Every link tag must have one *helper number(span)*, but that number should be visible to every user. I'm using **javascript** to do that, but I'm having the problem with **CSS**.

My code block is:

```css
.breadcumb li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #00c0c5;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}[data-talktochrome] {
    position: relative !important;
}.bstalktochrome {
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 9px;
    padding: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    max-width: 40px;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: -10px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    line-height: normal;
    z-index: 100000;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcumb">
<li><a href="http://*.vn" title="" data-talktochrome="153"><span class="bstalktochrome">153</span>Nhịp sống số</a></li>
<li><a href="http://*.vn/tin/thi-truong" title="" data-talktochrome="154"><span class="bstalktochrome">154</span>Thị trường</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please help.

**Update 1:**
The testing page is: http://nhipsongso.tuoitre.vn/tin/thi-truong/20150924/iphone-6s-va-6s-plus-ve-vn-som-gia-cao/974668.html

But there are no *helper number(span)* yet

To show the *helper number(span)*, you should open console panel of the browser and run these codes:

```
        sohientai = 1
        $("body").append("<style>.bstalktochrome_btn {display:none}.bstalktochrome {border-radius:50%; font-size: 9px;padding: 2px;font-weight: bold;max-width: 40px;position: absolute !important;top: -10px !important;left: 0px !important;line-height: normal;z-index:100000;background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.24);} [data-talktochrome]{position:relative !important;} </style>")
        $("a").each(function(){
            $(this).prepend('<span class="bstalktochrome">'+sohientai+'</span>')
            $(this).attr("data-talktochrome", sohientai)
            sohientai++
        })
```

Comment: if you increase the value of the `background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.24);` like `background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.55);` than you can see some difference which means the color you provided is creating the problem

Answer (score 1):

Change CSS like below

```
.breadcumb li
{ padding-top:15px
}


.breadcumb li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #00c0c5;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}[data-talktochrome] {
    position: relative !important;
}.bstalktochrome {
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 9px;
    padding: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    max-width: 40px;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: -12px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    line-height: normal;
    z-index: 100000;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

Comment: Thanks **arun**, i know that the *padding* can help, but that will make all other links of the page become more urly then normal. I just want to show the *helper numer* but should not change any other elements's position.

Answer (score 0):

Its possibly not a case of layering (z-index) but a case of cropping. The parent container might have `overflow:hidden` on it, and therefore crops the part that you cant see. Its just a guess but worth taking a look at. If the page is public, sharing a link would be very helpful to determine the actual problem

EDIT: As expected, on you topmost issue the `breadcrumb` class has overflow:hidden, you can change it to:

```
.breadcumb {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And your right-column problem can be solved with the same method (remove overflow attribute, add display attribute):

```
.bl-ar {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}
```

Comment: thanks Zedd, i've added the **Update 1** section for the testing page, please help me with your guess. I think you can solve my problem.

Comment: @TrầnQuốcHoàinew2015 ive updated my answer with a solution to your problem

Comment: @zeed thanks for your helping, but it's just only a testing page. Actually, i'm writing a chrome extension to insert *helper number(span)* when a command was call. I just want this will work on all other sites like youtube or facebook too.

So that's not a good idea to add *display: inline-block;* to specific elements have the problem.

If we can use javascript to change all  *display: hidden;* to  *display: inline-block;*?

Comment: Well that changes the problem altogether. You should probably have another approach entirely, (possibly a bad idea to inject the element inline as you do). I would create a new element on top of everything and grab the positions of the relevant elements, and then position my numbers on the new layer at the same spots (this would probably interfear least with the actual page)

Comment: could you give me some simple keys for the coding, i understand your idea, a new **div** layer will create, but i don't know how to add css for the  *helper number (span)* and the css of the **div** layer.

Comment: @TrầnQuốcHoàinew2015 thats too far outside the span of the question here, but check jQuerys .offset(). Layer should be 100% wide, 100% high. Aboslute position everything